# Using 'whom' for things

Tags: whom

Is this sentence correct (especially the usage of whom)?

> In addition, it might jump to a random vertex in the graph, whom the
>   current vertex is not necessarily connected to, with a certain
>   probability.

Answer (score 3):

No, the writer should use "which" instead of "whom." It is also not clear what the "with a certain probability" clause refers to.

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, it might jump to a random vertex in the graph to which
>   the current vertex is not necessarily connected, with a certain
>   probability.

Removing the comma after graph shows that the "with a certain probability" clause refers to "it" jumping, and not to its connection to the "current vertex." Am I understanding that clause?

Or you could try:

> In addition and with a certain probability, it might jump to a random
>   vertex in the graph to which the current vertex is not necessarily
>   connected.

Apologies if I'm not understanding that final clause.

Answer (score 1):

The word ["whom"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whom) is the objective form of ["who"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/who) which is used in reference to persons. So unless the vertex is connected to a person, it is not correct to use it.

The word ["which"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/which) probably would be better.